# Where is the web_ui wizard in the Dart Editor?

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-editor

The [Get Started with Web UI](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/web-ui/) Dart tutorial displays this image: [image: Dart Editor version 0.5.0_r21823]

...but I don't see the "Web application (using the web_ui library)" option in the latest Dart Editor (version 0.5.0_r21823). Is the tutorial outdated or do I need to do something special to have the web_ui wizard included in the Editor?

**Edit:** Maybe this is a Linux-only issue? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipsdK.jpg) of my editor.

Comment: I am on the same editor version as you and I see the option as per the image. I did not have to do any special configuration to enable it.

Comment: Latest Eclipse plugin (not the standalone editor) shows all options - could you post a screenshot of your "new project" wizard?

Comment: Hmm maybe it is Linux related? (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04). Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/La6yaxX

Comment: I tried a previous build of the editor (21658) and got the same thing. I think web_ui integration is not included in the linux-64bit builds.

Comment: weird. can you manually import it? create a web application and import "web_ui" via pub?

Comment: Well, I can do that. Was just wondering if the tutorial was outdated, but it seems the the build doesn't include it.

Comment: Is it possible that the screen is just too small for all the options? If you click on "Web application" and push down arrow key (or scroll with the scroll wheel), does the last option come to view?

Comment: Oh, Juhana. I feel SO stupid now. The selection box is not resizable, but scrollable it is! Mousewheel did the trick (shame). This is a stupid UI issue that I didn't think about (Ubuntu hides the scrollbar until you hover it). Please post it as an answer and I will accept it. :)

Comment: Yeah, the whitespace at the end seems to be static instead of dynamic... might just be worth a bug report even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog box might just be too small to contain all the options. Click on "Web application" and push down key or scroll with the mouse wheel to bring the last option to view.

Comment: I feel really dumb for not having noticed it but on the other side this is clearly an UI flaw, at list on Ubuntu/compiz. :)